# Dataflow SQL: Bad pipeline options

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud

I am trying to create a test dataflow SQL job but it always fails after around 6 minutes.

Here is my gcloud command:
`gcloud dataflow sql query 'WITH avg_nums AS( SELECT random_numbers FROM bigquery.table.`test_project.test_dataset.input_table `ORDER BY RAND()LIMIT 5)SELECT AVG(random_numbers) AS number,current_timestamp() AS date_time FROM avg_nums' \ --job-name= job_name \ --region=us-central1 \ --bigquery-project=test_project \ --bigquery-dataset=test_dataset \ --bigquery-table=test_table \ --max-workers=2 \ --num-workers=1 \ --worker-region=us-central1 \ --bigquery-write-disposition=write-append \ --disable-public-ips \ --service-account-email=dataflow_test@test_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \ --subnetwork=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test_project/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/test_subnetwork`

The input_table has one column called random_numbers with nothing but integers in it. I tested the SQL query in BigQuery editor and all worked fine, so I just made a few syntax changes as above to ensure dataflow can interpret my SQL query accordingly.

Dataflow logs show this error:
"Error occurred in the launcher container: Template launch failed. See console logs."

Logs show this error:
{"severity":"INFO","time":"2023/10/06 13:10:58.341418","line":"exec.go:66","message":"Invalid/unsupported arguments for SQL job launch: Bad pipeline options"}
{"severity":"INFO","time":"2023/10/06 13:12:58.348998","line":"exec.go:52","message":"java failed with exit status 42"}
{"severity":"INFO","time":"2023/10/06 13:12:58.349090","line":"launch.go:77","message":"Template launch failed: exit status 42"}

There is literally no article in either Google's official documentation or community page or even here on Stack overflow.

Has anyone come across this issue? If so, can you help me resolve this? Thanks

I have tried:
Added all the necessary permissions, ensured the SQL syntax is fine, checked the official documentation, searched the web, tried removing various parameters from pipeline options, tried creating the same job in Dataflow SQL workspace,...

Comment: Looks like you do not use external IPs. Have you checked https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/routes-firewall?

Comment: Hey @XQHu, I'm not sure I follow. Are you referring to making sure that the VMs are set up correctly to handle working with internal IPs only? Could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: I mean since you use `--disable-public-ips`, please make sure your VMs are configured correctly base on the doc I showed.